# Is there a program i can use to find a hidden message in a BMP file?

Tags: encryption

I am working on a puzzle and think there is a message hidden in one of the files that is a BMP file. I am wondering if there is a program somewhere that could find it?

Comment: Did you check Wikipedia?

Comment: The general answer is no given that there are arbitrary ways to encode such messages, some more subtle than others and these can also be masked with encryption under an unknown key completely thwarting any information extraction.

Comment: If its just a simple puzzle the color values might be even (or mod 4) and the information was added to those (odd values or reminder of mod 4).